# WordPress DB Query to count number of users registered per day

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I would like to know the number of users that registered each day in WordPress via a SQL query.

I am aware to do this properly we'd need a table of all the dates or some funky query to emulate the dates, however I'm after the simple option and it's OK to skip days with 0 registrations.

An output something like this would be amazing:

```
day        total_users
01-01-2014    10
02-01-2014    19
etc....
23-04-2014    5
```

**Note:** I did check to see if there was a similar question asked, there was a generic one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314320/sql-query-to-count-registered-users-per-day), but not wordpress specific.

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In wordpress the user table is wp_users and you can run the following query to get what you are looking at

```
select 
count(*) as total_users ,
date(user_registered) as reg_date 
from wp_users 
group by reg_date 
having total_users > 0
```

Comment: Our tables are prefixed slightly differently and that worked brilliantly thank you.

Comment: Yeah while installing WP you can set the table prefix, I have one installed on my local dev environment but no prefixed. But yes glad that it worked for you.